# How to insert JSON into snowflake variant column using pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON data that I am pulling from an API. Below is a sample from that data:

```
{'Clients' : [{'id' : 123, 'name' : 'client ABC inc'},
{'id' : 456, 'name' : 'client XYZ inc'}]}
```

I want to insert it in its entirety into a variant column of a snowflake table using pyspark dataframe. How can I do so? I am looking for schema definition and dataframe write steps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark Solution:

From [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000093RKojSAG/how-can-i-insert-json-string-to-snowflake-variant-column-using-python). You can create a table and define the schema. Then insert into it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import snowflake.connector
import json
 
# Sample JSON string
var = {
    "student": {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "age": 10
    }
}
 
# Connect to your Snowflake account
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    account='xxx',
    user='xxx',
    password='xxx',
    database='xxx',
    schema='xxx'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("create or replace transient table test_json_load (scr variant)")
    cs.execute("insert into test_json_load (select PARSE_JSON('%s'))" % json.dumps(var))
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()
```

SNOWPARK Solution:

You could create a dataframe from your json and then append it to existing table (in example below called `json_example` using `mode = 'append'`., This mode appends to the table if it exists, otherwise creates a new table. In the example below the credentials2 is a .py file containing all the connection details.

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from credentials2 import connection_parameters

session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()

df = session.create_dataframe([['{"Clients" : [{"id" : "123", "name" : "client ABC inc"},\
                                {"id" : "456", "name" : "client XYZ inc"}]}']], schema=["json_var"])
df.write.mode('append').save_as_table('json_example')
```

Comment: I am not using snowpark. I need a solution in pyspark. I tried to use String type in the schema for variant target column. However, I got string value of JSON in the target column. I can't query that data using JSON query capabilities in snowflake.